# Change JButton background color when mouse on it (not rollover)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I created a JFrame with 5 buttons, 1 of them is a play button which user could press to play an audio file, the rest of them are the choices which user are required to choose the correct one after listening to the audio.

I want the buttons to change color when the mouse is over them.

I disabled the choice buttons then play the audio file, used SwingWorker to wait until the audio file is finished then enable the buttons again.

Firstly I used ButtonModel and changeListener to set background color. Of course they worked well when mouse rollover them after the audio clip finished playing.

But I found a problem is that, if i moved my mouse to the button while the audio was playing, the button was enabled after the audio finished but it did not change its color.

Appreciate for any help!

TLDR: There are two situations

(1) I pressed the play button, did not move the mouse pointer such that the pointer stay over the play button. **AFTER** the 4 buttons were enabled, I moved the mouse pointer to any one of them, the changelistener works prefectly.

(2) I pressed the play button, moved the mouse pointer to any one of the 4 buttons **BEFORE** the 4 buttons were enabled, the color of the buttons did not change after the buttons were enabled.

The complete demo of the JFrame is attached, it could be run perfectly with MigLayout libraries.

```
public class demo extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane, panelBtn, panelWord;
private JButton btnPlay, btnStop, btnWord0, btnWord1, btnWord2, btnWord3;
public static void main (String args[]){
    demo testing = new demo();
}

public demo(){
    super("Demonstrating problem");
    init();
    setVisible(true);
}

private void init(){
    customizedChangeListener clBtn = new customizedChangeListener();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 673, 512);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    panelBtn = new JPanel();
    panelBtn.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow][]", ""));
    contentPane.add(panelBtn, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    panelWord = new JPanel();
    panelWord.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow,fill][grow,fill]", "[grow,fill][grow,fill]"));
    contentPane.add(panelWord, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    btnPlay = new JButton("Play");
    btnPlay.addActionListener(new playAcitonListener());
    panelBtn.add(btnPlay, "cell 0 0, align center");

    btnWord0 = new JButton("A");
    btnWord0.addChangeListener(clBtn);
    panelWord.add(btnWord0, "cell 0 0");

    btnWord1 = new JButton("B");
    btnWord1.addChangeListener(clBtn);
    panelWord.add(btnWord1, "cell 1 0");

    btnWord2 = new JButton("C");
    btnWord2.addChangeListener(clBtn);
    panelWord.add(btnWord2, "cell 0 1");

    btnWord3 = new JButton("D");
    btnWord3.addChangeListener(clBtn);
    panelWord.add(btnWord3, "cell 1 1");

    enableBtn(false);
}

private class customizedChangeListener implements ChangeListener{
    JButton rolledBtn;
    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        rolledBtn = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if (rolledBtn.getModel().isRollover())
            rolledBtn.setBackground(Color.green);
        else
            rolledBtn.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
    }
}

private class playAcitonListener implements ActionListener{
    JButton pressedBtn;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        pressedBtn = (JButton)e.getSource();
        if (pressedBtn.equals(btnPlay)){
            btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
            new SwingWorker<Void ,Void>(){

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void done() {
                    enableBtn(true);
                }
            }.execute();
        }
    }
}

private void enableBtn (boolean idx) {
    if (idx == true){
        btnWord0.setEnabled(true);
        btnWord1.setEnabled(true);
        btnWord2.setEnabled(true);
        btnWord3.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else if (idx == false){
        btnWord0.setEnabled(false);
        btnWord1.setEnabled(false);
        btnWord2.setEnabled(false);
        btnWord3.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I don't see how "*code snippets*" are a runnable example. You are describing all sorts of issues that we can't test and see. Please post the *relevant* code that we can run.

Comment: I have updated the code such that it is now a complete example, sorry for the previous mistakes!

Answer (score 2):

You can detect when mouse is over button or some other element with this code:

```
    button.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) {
        // your code here (color of button)
    }
} );
```

And like @DebilsHnd said change color back with mouseExited().

Comment: And in the mouseExited() event change the color back to its original color.

Comment: Have tried this but cannot achieve what I want exactly. I want to enable the button and so the changing color function **after** the audio finished playing. I could add the mouseListener after the audio finished playing, but the same problem came up, if I move my mouse to the button befroe the audio finished, the button would not change color afterwards.

Comment: The buttons model is updated automatically by the `JButton` when `mouseEnter` and `mouseExit` occurs, there shouldn't be any need to re-invent the wheel.  The issue the OP is having has to do with something they are not showing us

Comment: I have edited and made it clear in the TLDR section, and I have typed the whole runnable demo, please check : )